# Developing app for Amazon Fire TV Stick?

Tags: android, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv, leanback

I want to develop application for the Amazon fire stick but I am not aware of it. I am unclear about some points

1. Can we create a standalone app that can run into the Amazon fire stick without need to Android phone or tablet?
2. If we can create the standalone app then can we call web-service to retrieve data from the server?

It would be great help if you can help me to clear with these questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we create a standalone app that can run into the Amazon fire stick without need to Android phone or tablet?

Yes. It is a first-class Android device on its own.

> If we can create the standalone app then can we call web-service to retrieve data from the server?

If you hold the `INTERNET` permission and the device has suitable connectivity, then yes. This is no different than any other Android phone, tablet, TV, or toaster.